# How should I correctly do modelling with this data?

Tags: database-design

I have created Conceptual data model and Physical data model with this information:
Conceptual data model:
[image]

Physical data model:
[image]
I want 'Purchase' to have many 'Ticket'. For example, something like this:
(PurchaseID, TicketID)
(    1          1    )
(    1          1    )
(    1          2    )
(    1          2    )
This could correspond to 'One purchase with 4 tickets, 2 one kind of tickets and 2 another kind of tickets)
How can I model correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a 1-many linking table

```
PurchaseTickets (
 PKey INT identity(1,1) primary Key, 
 PurchaseID INT References Purchase(PurchaseId), 
 TicketID INT References Ticket(TicketId)
)
```

Remove TicketId from Purchase

I recommend changing field "Price" on Ticket to CostPrice (not the same as Purchase.Price)

Don't store duration on Ticket - can be calculated from DATEDIFF(DAY, Start, End)
If you have Currency on Purchase.Price, you also need Currency on Ticket, or at least a conversion rate to make same as purchase price... gets hectic - might need a Date, CurrencyFRom, CurrencyTo, XRate reference table with exchange rates over time, linking on... purchasedate.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it now and it works 

Comment: @Justas - excellent - please accept the answer :)